# How to change table numbering scheme at a new section?

Tags: sectioning, floats, numbering

I am trying to implement a style to name tables and figures depending on the section for a thesis and can't figure out how to do it with LaTeX.

In the end it should look like this:
[image]

and my document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Start}
Start text
\section{Middle}
Middle text
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    first table\\
    \end{tabular}
\caption{A normal table}
\end{table}

\section*{Supplemental}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        table in supplemental part\\
    \end{tabular}
\caption{This should read: ``Table S1: caption text''}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I don't want to change the naming permanently, it should continue normally in the next chapter. Is there any easy way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Does this also require `hyperref` functionality? Why do you mention chapter when your MWE contains no `\chapter` and uses `article`?

Comment: The functionality of `hyperref` is not necessary but would be nice of course. `\chapter` is in my original document but I wanted to keep the example small, just assume next section instead of chapter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following solution does *not* support [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) since it re-uses counters associated with supplemental tables (or figures).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\newcounter{mytable}\newcounter{myfigure}
\titleformat{\section}% <command>
  [hang]% <shape>
  {\setcounter{mytable}{\value{table}}\setcounter{myfigure}{\value{figure}}% Store table/figure counters
   \setcounter{table}{0}\global\def\thetable{S\arabic{table}}%
   \setcounter{figure}{0}\global\def\thefigure{S\arabic{figure}}%
   \normalfont\Large\bfseries}% <format>
  {\setcounter{table}{\value{mytable}}\setcounter{figure}{\value{myfigure}}% Restore table/figure counters
   \global\def\thetable{\arabic{table}}%
   \global\def\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}%
   \thesection}% <label>
  {2.3ex plus.2ex}% <sep>
  {}% <before code>
  %[]% <after code>
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\section{Start}
Start text

\section{Middle}
Middle text
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering STUFF
\caption{A normal table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering STUFF
\caption{A normal table}
\end{table}

\section*{Supplemental}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering SUPPLEMENTAL STUFF
\caption{A supplemental table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering SUPPLEMENTAL STUFF
\caption{A supplemental table}
\end{table}

\section{Last}
End text
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering STUFF
\caption{A normal table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering STUFF
\caption{A normal table}
\end{table}

\section*{Supplemental}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering SUPPLEMENTAL STUFF
\caption{A supplemental table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering SUPPLEMENTAL STUFF
\caption{A supplemental table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I've used [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) to hook into the sectional unit `\section` that conditionally executes certain parts of typesetting the heading (the settings are kept similar to the original `article` formatting). The label and separator part of the heading is only called when using `\section`, and therefore not "called" or used in `\section*`.

The concept is based on storing the current value of the `table` (and `figure`) counter in `mytable` (`myfigure`), after which it is set to `0`. Then, *only* if you're using `\section` its value is restored. At both instances the display of the counter is renewed to prepend `S` or not.

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I intended and is highly appreciated with the coming deadline.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your objective correctly, you're aiming to number the tables (and figures?) as plain integers starting with 1 in the "main" body of the text, and to restart the numbering at 1, but now with an "S" prefixed, once you're in the supplemental part of the document.

You don't indicate if you've already defined a special command to make some modifications to the layout and other aspects of the document's appearance, so I'll assume you haven't done so. A relatively clean way to proceed would be to define a new command, say `\startsupplement`, in the preamble and to invoke this command at the start of that part of the document. This new command could be defined as follows:

```
\newcommand\startsupplement{%
    \makeatletter 
       \setcounter{table}{0}
       \renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic\c@table}
       \setcounter{figure}{0}
       \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\@arabic\c@figure}
    \makeatother}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is almost what I thought of but I still need the counters after the supplement in the next part of the document.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand: The supplemental section doesn't occur at the *end* of the document but might occur anywhere (say, at the end of a chapter)? After the supplement, then, you want to go back to "regular" numbering (without the "S" prefix) of tables and figures?

Comment: Mico: exactly, each chapter gets a supplemental section and then then next chapter starts and should use the "regular" numbering again. The background is the following, the content of the chapters comes from separate scientific papers, each paper has it's own supplemental and the whole document should reflect this structure.

Comment: It would be helpful to know *which* LaTeX document class you use. (For instance, if you were using the `book` document class, or one that's derived from `book`, all figure and table numbers would be reset at the start of each chapter automatically. Therefore, there'd be no need to pursue anything more elaborate than what's implemented in the `\startsupplement` command above. For now, I must surmise you're *not* using the `book` document class.) Armed with knowledge of the type of document class you do employ, it may be possible to design a setup that is compatible with `hyperref`.

Comment: Thanks for all the thought you put into this. I have not specified a class because I am still trying out different options. So far I `scrbook` seems to work nicely.