# Prefix figure number for a given section only

Tags: floats, numbering, appendices

My document consists of several chapters. At the end of each chapter there is a section for appendices. What would be the correct way to number figures and tables in the appendices as. For example, Figure 1 in the appendix of chapter three should be numbered as: 3.A1

I have found some [general ways](https://biobeat.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/prefix-figure-numbering-in-appendix/) of how to prefix figure numbers for appendices, but not for my special case.

Comment: Probably [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41318/how-to-change-table-numbering-scheme-at-a-new-section), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391540/renumbering-figure-in-latex), [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39315/how-to-change-the-numbering-for-different-figures) or [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85776/change-figure-numbering-for-appendix?rq=1) can help?